# SharedPreferences Not retrieving JsonArray, JsonObject after device reboot

Tags: android, json, arrays

I have set `JsonArray` and `JsonObject` to Application class to make this objects global.
The values stored in json array retrieve before the device is reboot. after reboot json array show blank squre '[]' bracket. with out reboot It shows me the value of json array. but after reboot it doesn't. any suggestions or guide so that I can do this.

this is `Application` class

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application{
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PrefsFile";
private JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
private jsonObject jsonObj=new jsonObject();

public JSONArray getjsonArray() {
    return jsonArray;
}

public void setjsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
}

public jsonObject getjsonObj() {
    return jsonObj;
}

public void setjjsonObj(jsonObject jsonObj) {
    this.jsonObj = jsonObj;
}
```

}

here I am setting JsonArray & JsonObject

```
// jsonObj, jsonArray declare as class variables 
                       //getting global JsonArray object

               final MyApplicationClass AppObj=(MyApplicationClass )getApplicationContext();
               final JSONArray jsonArray=AppObj.getJsonAlarmArray();

              // getting name of sharedPreferences file & mode
              sharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences(MyApplicationClass.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              final JSONObject jsonObj =AppObj.getJsonObj();

                 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(some condition)
                {
                    jsonObj.put("value1", 1234);
                    jsonObj.put("value2", 234);
                    jsonObj.put("value3", 3);

                }
                else if(some condition))
                {
                    jsonObj.put("value1", 12314);
                    jsonObj.put("value2", 2314);
                    jsonObj.put("value3", 31);
                }

                jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
                AppObj.setJsonAlarmArray(jsonArray);
            editor= sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
                System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
                editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

this way I am retrieving the json array

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            sharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences(MyApplicationClass.PREFS_NAME, 0);

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray=((MyApplicationClass)getApplication()).getJsonAlarmArray();
                System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
                Toast.makeText(TypesActivity.this, ""+jsonArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: it seems like you do not understand you own code ... where is the part where you are loading data from SharedPreferences to jsonarray ?

Comment: editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString()); this is line where json object is seting to SP &  JSONArray jsonArray=((MyApplicationClass)getApplication()).getJsonAlarmArray(); where I am retrieving it. @Selvin

Comment: sorry, this is actual method .getJsonArray() not this one getJsonAlarmArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to read the json from `SharedPreferences`:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        sharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences(MyApplicationClass.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String jsonArrayString = sharedPrefs.getString("key", null);
        try {
            if (jsonArrayString != null) {
                JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(jsonArrayString) 
                System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
                Toast.makeText(TypesActivity.this, ""+jsonArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: checking this...@blackbelt

Comment: now jsonArray is retrieving from SP. but now it replacing first array by second. canyou help out of this. @blackbelt

Comment: what does it mean? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: What I think he needs is retreiving a JSON array at Application start, not in onClick since he puts new values and then when you click btn2 it retrieves old ones.

Comment: jsonObj.put("value1", 1234); jsonObj.put("value2", 234);           jsonObj.put("value3", 3); I have set this three values to one task. for another again I have to set this three values. but when I set this this values for 2nd task the values for 1st task is replaced. @blackbelt

Comment: you should use different keys for store different objects inside sharedpreferences. for instance key1 and key2. and use key1 for retrive jsono of the first task and key2 for the second task

Comment: but if I have multiple numbers of task, then what should I do? @blackbelt

Comment: if you want to use sharedpreferences you need to provide a unique key for eache entry.

Comment: ok.. can I put each task as different JsonObject or JsonArray in sharedpreferences. @blackbelt

Comment: can you give me some idea how to do this...?@blackbelt

Comment: i got some idea....                                  SharedPreferences prefs = ...;
final int count = 50;
final String KEY_COUNT = "COUNT";
final String KEY_VAL_PREFIX = "VAL_";
int values[] = new int[count];

/*
 * ... put some stuff in values[] ...
 */

final Editor sped = prefs.edit();
sped.putInt(KEY_COUNT, count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    sped.putInt(KEY_VAL_PREFIX + i, values[i]);
}
sped.commit();

Answer (score 0):

Save your Json string in a file and update the file every time When you update the Json object. When you load Json again, you can load it from the file